# working around unescaped $ in json return

Tags: json, angularjs

I can't find anything quite like this, but then, I've never seen json constructed this way, so I don't know the purposes behind it. I don't have means to modify the endpoint, either. (Possible cause: some bug in java that's improperly escaping things.)

Here's what the json basically looks like:

```
{ "thingName" : { "$" : "name-of-thing" } }
```

When I look at the actual response, name-of-thing is in there. When I bring it in via $http and add it to scope, I get an empty set. Here's the js:

```
$scope.getName = function(val) {
    $http.get('http://something/something/names?KeywordText=' + val)
        .success(function(res) {
            $scope.results = res;
    });
};
```

But if I do an ng-repeat on results.thingName, I get just an empty {}, repeated for every name returned. How do I get the contents (name-of-thing) and bypass that single $ in the return?

many many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular ignores variables prefixed with the dollar sign. One possible solution would be to rewrite your response (replace the dollar sign with something else) before adding it to the scope.

**Update**: Try something like this:

```
var dollarRename = 'dlr';

function renameDollar(obj) {
  for (var k in obj) {
    if (k === '$') {
      obj[dollarRename] = obj.$;
      delete obj.$;
      k = dollarRename;
    }
    if (typeof obj[k] === "object" && obj[k] !== null) {
      renameDollar(obj[k]);
    }
  }
}

.success(function (res) {
  renameDollar(res);
  $scope.results = res;
});
```

Comment: That's sort of what I've been trying to figure out how to do, but I'm not sure how. Is it possible to do something like str_replace in js, and find all '$' and replace them with something else?